# SQL - Join tables with same id

Tags: sql

I'm trying to achieve something in SQL. I will give you an example of what I want.

I want to link my players to custom PETS.

For instance I have these tables with custom fields. (uuid is the player's uuid)

Tables are Pet1, Pet2, they have same rows (uuid, inventory, level) and also other rows which are different from other (coordinates)

**Pet1:**

| uuid | inventory | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | somedata | 2 |
| 235 | somedata | 8 |

**Pet2:**

| uuid | inventory | level | coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | somedata | 5 | 0 |
| 526 | somedata | 7 | 123 |

Let say my player's uuid is 123, so I'd like to get that :

**Pet1 desired output:**

| inventory | level |
| --- | --- |
| somedata | 2 |

**Pet2 desired output:**

| inventory | level | coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| somedata | 5 | 0 |

And I would like to access to these data with these kind of commands :

```
Pet1.inventory, Pet1.level
Pet2.coordonates
```

etc..

Thanks for help

Comment: Tables have rows and columns.  I'm really confused on what the rows and columns are in your data.

Comment: Tables are : Pet1, Pet2, Pet3
rows of Pet1 are uuid, inventory, level
these rows contain the values 1, ..., 2

Comment: My understanding of your question uuid, inventory, level... are columns not rows. Then "123, somedata, 2" is a row of table Pet1.

Answer (score 0):

Edited and updated based on the new info in your comment - the below should be sufficient if you only have a few 'Pet' tables. If you have many 'Pet' tables, the query will be slow due to the number of joins required.

```
SELECT
    uuid,
    inventory,
    level,
    coordinates

    FROM Pet1
    
    LEFT JOIN Pet2
    ON Pet1.uuid = Pet2.uuid
    
    WHERE uuid = '123'
```

This query will give something like the following output:

| uuid | inventory | coordinates | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | somedata | NULL | 2 |
| 123 | somedata | 0 | 5 |

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No, the tables names are Pet1, Pet2, Pet3 sorry if it was badly explained

Comment: Yes but how can I identify which row is Pet1, Pet2 etc.. I have also updated my post

Comment: @Kataklycm You could use an identifier column. For example, a column in 'Pet1' table named 'Source_Table', with every Row populated as 'Pet1'. Then a column in 'Pet2' table also named 'Source_Table', with every row populated as 'Pet2' (do the same fo every 'Pet' table). Then you can include 'Source_Table' in the SELECT clause, and on each row of the output there will be an indicator for which table the data originated from.